# system call generate error when cmd is running smothly

Tags: c++, command-line, system

I am trying to run enfuse via my c++ code to hdr fuse some image. My code is basically this:

```
  std::string cmd=getCmd();
  system(cmd.c_str());
```

getcmd would return a string like this:

```
"C:\code\Debug\enfuse" --hard-mask      "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Temp\pp\0-0.jpg"        "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Temp\pp\1-0.jpg "        "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Temp\pp\2-0.jpg "        "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Temp\pp\3-0.jpg "        "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Temp\pp\4-0.jpg "    -o "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Temp\pp\0fuse.tif"
```

when I run this string using the above code, I am getting this error:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

but when if I copy the string and paste it inside a command window, it works well without any problem.

I checked and found that I remove the quotes from directory entries then it works well, but if I remove the quotes then if a path has space, the command string is wrong and it is not working.

Why this command works well on a command window, but not using system?

I am developing on windows, but this code should be platform independent and I should be able to compile it on Linux.

## Edit 1

I noted that there is an space before quote on some part of string and hence I removed them and the string became:

```
"C:\code\Debug\enfuse" --hard-mask      "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Temp\pp\0-0.jpg"        "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Temp\pp\1-0.jpg"        "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Temp\pp\2-0.jpg"        "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Temp\pp\3-0.jpg"        "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Temp\pp\4-0.jpg"    -o "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Temp\pp\0fuse.tif"
```

this string when copied to a cmd window, works well but when I run it via system call as above, I am getting this error:

```
The input line is too long.
```

Comment: Try \\ inplace of \ C:\\Users\\m\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pp\\2-0.jpg

Comment: thanks, but this did not solved the problem as the strings are generated automatically and hence they are already escaped properly. Please note that if I remove the quotes, the system call works so the problem is quotes and not the actual path.